# Where can I find the inner working of csr matrix addition in the SciPy library?

Tags: c++, numpy, scipy

I'm writing my own program that can convert form COO form to CSR form in C++. Where I get stuck is trying to figure out how to do addition with CSR format in an efficient way. I currently have a way  to find matches of entries in an A and B matrix stored in CSR form, but I'd like to find where SciPy/NumPy actually has the code for addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a start:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/sparse

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h

I think addition is implemented via a more general binary operation.

Looks like most of the code is in the .h files rather than .cxx; but you can probably sort that out.

Comment: Thanks a million, I was digging through the documentation for hours trying to find it. Don't know python so I didn't think to look for a generic binary operator.